# How to get a list of active branches for a project using TeamCity REST API?

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to find a list of all branches for a given project. Is it possible to get this information through Teamcity REST API? I found a different answer showing how to get a list of branches for a given build configuration:

[Can you use the team city rest api to fetch plan branch names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116480/can-you-use-the-team-city-rest-api-to-fetch-plan-branch-names)

But this way I would have to run the query for all build configurations under given project.

However TeamCity has a concept of "active" branches on a given project. I am wondering if it is possible to fetch exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is possible now.

> Implemented for 2017.1 as an experimental features:
>
> - listing of the branches for a project (merged list of all project's build configuration's branches) via .../app/rest/projects/XXX/branches?locator=policy:XXX
> - additional branch node fields: "active", "lastActivity" timestamp, "builds" (with locator), available via "fields" parameter of the request
> - added "branches" into buildType node, available only via "fields" parameter of the request

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44148#comment=27-2018515

I'm using exactly this url: `http://TCSERVERADDRESS/app/rest/projects/PROJECTNAME/branches` and it works good for me.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCtiy REST API does not support showing active branches now. You are welcome to drop a [feature request in the tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW)

Answer (score 1):

Posting on here since I have ran into this recently, I found that by running a network trace in my browser, the following which returns active branches.

```
https://ci.{Your org here}.com/app/rest/buildTypes/id:{Your project's build config id here}/branches?locator=policy:ACTIVE_VCS_BRANCHES,includeGroups:true&fields=branch(internalName,name,default,active,groupFlag)
```

This returns the list of branches that you would find in the dropdown in Team City UI,

There are a few other policies, including the following: VCS_BRANCHES, ACTIVE_VCS_BRANCHES, HISTORY_BRANCHES, ACTIVE_HISTORY_BRANCHES, ACTIVE_HISTORY_AND_ACTIVE_VCS_BRANCHES, ALL_BRANCHES

Hope this helps someone!